# Show file in new tab when clicking on Preview button in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to show a file in a new tab when clicking on the Preview button in a LWC component. The below code is showing the preview:

```javascript
      wiredResult({data, error}){ 
        if(data){ 
            console.log(data)
            this.filesList = Object.keys(data).map(item=>({"label":data[item],
             "value": item,
             "url":`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/${item}`
            }))
            console.log(this.filesList)
        }
        if(error){ 
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    previewHandler(event){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes:{ 
                pageName:'filePreview',
            },
            state:{ 
                selectedRecordId: event.target.dataset.id
            }
        })
      }
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: Hi Saroj, I am not getting any error. the above code is opening with in the tab. I want to open as a subtab.

Answer (score 0):

This code is opening a subtab within the console

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
   type: 'standard__recordPage',
   attributes: {
      recordId: event.target.dataset.id,
      actionName: 'view'
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previewHandler(event) {
    const fileId = event.target.dataset.id;
    const fileUrl = `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/${fileId}`;
    window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
}
```

**previewHandler** function, the window.open method is used to open the file URL in a new tab ('_blank'). This approach directly opens the file preview in a new tab without navigating to the standard file preview page.

Make sure to replace `'@salesforce/apex/FileController.getFilesList'` with the correct Apex method or wire adapter you are using to retrieve the file data.